# How to return radio checked object with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="rdName" id="uniqueID1" value="1" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="rdName" id="uniqueID2" value="2">
<input type="radio" name="rdName" id="uniqueID3" value="3">
```

jQuery #1

```
$('input:radio[name=rdName]:checked').val();
```

jQuery #2

```
$('input[name=rdName]:checked');
```

jQuery #1 gets the value of checked radio, but I need to get the whole object to get the ID.
jQuery #2 get this (from Chrome Dev console). Object "0" is the actual object I need, but I am unable to just that.

```
0: HTMLInputElement
constructor: function Object()
context: HTMLDocument
length: 1
prevObject: Object
selector: input[name=rdName]:checked
__proto__: Object
```

Any ideas how to isolate the needed object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the elements in the jQuery object as an array:

```
var element = $('input[name=rdName]:checked')[0];
```

Or you can use the `get` method:

```
var element = $('input[name=rdName]:checked').get(0);
```

Comment: Thanks. Did not even think of accessing it as an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input:radio[name=rdName]:checked').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean this:

```
  alert($('input[name=rdName]:checked').get(0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("input[name='rdName']").on({
    'change': function () {
      $.each($("input[name='rdName']"), function () {
        var ObjectId;

        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          console.log(this); /* Jquery "this" you want */
          ObjectId = $(this).attr('id'); /* Id of above Jquery object */
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Give it a try, I hope it'll work according to your requirement as you want only jQuery Object to get attribute (id) of checked radio button. You may see jQuery object using this code in FireBug.